# How to calculate time between occurrence of an event in a timeseries dataframe

Tags: pandas, time-series, timedelta

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df
                       A     B      C    D   event  
Timestamp                                                      
1991-04-21 09:09:00   9.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  100.0     
1991-04-21 17:08:00   7.0   NaN    NaN  NaN  119.0     
1991-04-21 22:51:00   NaN   NaN  123.0  NaN    NaN     
1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  216.0     
1991-04-22 13:40:00   2.0   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN     
1991-04-22 16:56:00   7.0   NaN    NaN  NaN  211.0
```

using the code

```
df['delta_time'] = (df['event']-df['event'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

I get

```
Timestamp             A     B      C    D    event     delta_time 

1991-04-21 09:09:00   9.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  100.0     00:00:00
1991-04-21 17:08:00   7.0   NaN    NaN  NaN  119.0     07:59:00
1991-04-21 22:51:00   NaN   NaN  123.0  NaN    NaN     05:43:00
1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  216.0     08:44:00
1991-04-22 13:40:00   2.0   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN     06:05:00
1991-04-22 16:56:00   7.0   NaN    NaN  NaN  211.0     03:16:00
1991-04-23 07:25:00  11.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  257.0     14:29:00
```

but what I am looking for is

```
Timestamp                                                      
1991-04-21 09:09:00   9.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  100.0     00:00:00
1991-04-21 17:08:00   7.0   NaN    NaN  NaN  119.0     07:59:00
1991-04-21 22:51:00   NaN   NaN  123.0  NaN    NaN     NaN
1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  216.0     13:42:00
1991-04-22 13:40:00   2.0   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN
1991-04-22 16:56:00   7.0   NaN    NaN  NaN  211.0     09:21:00
1991-04-23 07:25:00  11.0  13.0    NaN  NaN  257.0     14:29:00
```

I want to calculate the time that has elapsed everytime an event occurs and omit the times when the event was an NaN. So what would be the correct approach to write that code.

Comment: this line `df['delta_time'] = (df['event']-df['event'].shift()).fillna(0) ` doesn't match your output or intent, as this subtracts the event column which is numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you want, I don't know if `Timestamp` is the index or not but this will work if it's not the index:

```
In [251]:
df['delta_time'] = df.loc[df['event'].notnull(),'Timestamp'].diff()
df

Out[251]:
            Timestamp     A     B      C   D  event  delta_time
0 1991-04-21 09:09:00   9.0  13.0    NaN NaN  100.0         NaT
1 1991-04-21 17:08:00   7.0   NaN    NaN NaN  119.0    07:59:00
2 1991-04-21 22:51:00   NaN   NaN  123.0 NaN    NaN         NaT
3 1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0  13.0    NaN NaN  216.0    14:27:00
4 1991-04-22 13:40:00   2.0   NaN    NaN NaN    NaN         NaT
5 1991-04-22 16:56:00   7.0   NaN    NaN NaN  211.0    09:21:00
```

if needed you need to call `reset_index` to restore the index back as a column

basically you mask the rows of interest based on where the 'event' is not null and then call `diff` to get the inter-row difference

Comment: @ EdChum Thanks a lot . Really appreciate your input